# Patch on a modified file

Tags: git, patch

I create some patchs that have to be applied on source code obtained using git, which are applied by the build tool (BitBake). It works well, but I don't know what it will do if the code is completely modified (say that the lines which are modified are removed, for example).

Answer (score 0):

`git apply <patch>` either apply the patch completely or does not apply at all. So, if git fails to cleanly apply the patch, it will abort the patch.